# Amazon RDS and Beanstalk use the same server

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds, aws-security-group

I am new to amazon services and am using Amazon RDS and beanstalk application . I have created the RDS instance outside of the beanstalk environment as suggested and use the same security code which works . **My question is how can I use my Amazon RDS server for beanstalk too ? ** . Right now I have 1 small tier server for RDS and another one for Beanstalk . Is there a way to use 1 server for both ? So they can both share the resources of 1 server .

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "RDS **server**"?

Comment: What I meant is that I am using Amazon RDS for Postgres and am using a T1.Micro server and I’m using another T1.Micro server for my beanstalk application . I was wondering if I could use the Micro server that I have my RDS and point beanstalk to it . Since I want my application and database to share the same server .

Comment: Yes, you can make Beanstalk point to your t1.micro RDS instance. Check out the environment variables section on [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.RDS.html).